# Получение значений на Master странице

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Добрый день. Хотел реализовать одну занятную вещь, но не могу дойти до нее.
у меня asp.net mvc4. Мне нужно на Master page вывести количество(просто какое-то число элементов списка). Список - количество заказов. Не знаю, как сделать так, чтобы не обращаясь к контроллеру можно было так вывести(за исключением BaseContorller - общего контроллера).
Может у Вас есть советы по выводу на глобальную страницу.

P.S. Данные нужно выводить на каждой странице, использующей MasterPage(варианты с "выведи модель из контроллера" - не подходят).

Comment: А где это число хранится? Почему бы не использовать сессию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу несколько вариантов решения.

1. *Статик класс =(* Скажем

> ```
> public static class OrderHelper
> {
>     static int GetCount()
>     {
>         //// 
>         return count ;
>     }
> }
> ```

2) *Создать экшен.*

> ```
> public class OrderControler : Controler
> {
>       public int Count(){ return count; }
> }
> ```

потом на странице где нужно использовать как

> @Html.Action("Count", "Order")

3)  *Определить BaseViewPage*

> ```
> public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
> {
>     public int OrdersCount () { return count; }
> }  
> public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> :  WebViewPage<TModel>
> {
>     public int OrdersCount() { return count; }
> }
> ```
>
> И в web.config подправить 
>  pageBaseType="NAMESPACE.BaseViewPage"

И тогда на любой странице можно будет вызвать

> OrdersCount()

P.S Выбирать вам. Меня только смущает

> использующей MasterPage

Неужели ASPX?